# cli is undefined in bpmn-js when using bpmn-js-cli react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bpmn-js

I am using bpmn-js to create bpmn flows. I want to create bpmn elements dynamically.

So i found that there is [bpmn-js-cli](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-cli#readme). So by using this code, I am integrating it in modeler

```
ModelerService._modeler = new Modeler({
      container: "#container",
      propertiesPanel: { parent: "#properties" },
      additionalModules: [
        CustomModule,CliModule
      ],
      moddleExtensions: {
            // custom extensions
      },
      keyboard: {
        bindTo: document,
      },
      cli: {
        bindTo: 'cli'
      }
    });
  }
```

Now according to documentation, i should get the `window.cli` to use this. But this variable is undefined.

Am i missing something? ANy help on this?